# std::auto_ptr, delete[] and leaks

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, auto-ptr

Why this code does **not** cause memory leaks?

```
int iterCount = 1000;
int sizeBig = 100000;
for (int i = 0; i < iterCount; i++)
{
   std::auto_ptr<char> buffer(new char[sizeBig]);
}
```

WinXP sp2, Compiler : BCB.05.03

Comment: In most cases if you pair new with delete[] and vice versa for non-trivial types this doesn't cause a leak - instead the program simply crashes when trying to deallocate memory.

Comment: You can try using boost::scoped_array instead of std::auto_ptr

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because you're (un)lucky. `auto_ptr` calls `delete`, not `delete []`. This is undefined behavior.

Try doing something like this and see if you get as lucky:

```
struct Foo
{
    char *bar;
    Foo(void) : bar(new char[100]) { }
    ~Foo(void) { delete [] bar; }
}

int iterCount = 1000;
int sizeBig = 100000;
for (int i = 0; i < iterCount; i++)
{
   std::auto_ptr<Foo> buffer(new Foo[sizeBig]);
}
```

The idea here is that your destructor for `Foo` will not be called.

---

The reason is something like this: When you say `delete[] p`, the implementation of `delete[]` is suppose to go to each element in the array, call its destructor, then free the memory pointed to by p. Similarly, `delete p` is suppose to call the destructor on p, then free the memory.

`char`'s don't have a destructor, so it's just going to delete the memory pointed to by p. In my code above, it is **not** going to destruct each element in the array (because it's not calling `delete[]`), so some Foo's will leave their local bar variable un-deleted.

Comment: Yes, I'm unlucky :) 
Thanks for explanation.

Comment: I compiled this but I am getting `_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)` error message, program crashes..this seems to indicate  it is getting deleted twice but don't know how that could happen

Comment: The destructor of `Foo` would in fact be called `iterCount`times but note `iterCount` * `sizeBig` times

Answer (score 3):

The auto_ptr will only live for the duration of the loop iteration and will release the object connected to it on iteration completion.

The compiler can see that in this case *new[]* can allocate space in the same way as *new* - without storing the number of elements anywhere since there's no need to call trivial `char` destructors - and that's why later when *delete* is called by the auto_ptr's destructor instead of *delete[]* it causes no problems since the memory block has actually been allocated in the *new*'s way and that allocation can be paired with *delete*.

This is an example of a thing not to do. It's up to the compiler to decide whether to replace *new[]* with *new*. Using *delete* instead of *delete[]* and vice versa is undefined behaviour.

See [Why would you write something like this? (intentionally not using delete [] on an array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787417/why-would-you-write-something-like-this-intentionally-not-using-delete-on-an) for discussion of *delete* vs *delete[]*.

Comment: So as GMan says: it's sheer luck *delete* is equivalent to *delete[]* here?

Comment: Well, yes, it's a result of the compiler trying to be clever and accidentially saving the developer.

Comment: It's not a result of compiler being clever, it is rather the result of compiler being lazy and doing the easiest thing (which in this case means that memory allocation for one element and array when PODs are involved works precisely the same). Of course this is U.B., so it is "sheer luck" that it works in a given implementation - and IIRC there are some real implementations where it does not work.