# Is delete[] equal to delete?

Tags: c++, memory-management, delete-operator

```
IP_ADAPTER_INFO *ptr=new IP_ADAPTER_INFO[100];
```

if I free using

```
delete ptr;
```

will it lead to memory leak, if not then why ?

This is disassembly code generated by VS2005

```
; delete ptr;
0041351D  mov         eax,dword ptr [ptr] 
00413520  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0ECh],eax 
00413526  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-0ECh] 
0041352C  push        ecx  
0041352D  call        operator delete (4111DBh) 
00413532  add         esp,4 

; delete []ptr;
00413535  mov         eax,dword ptr [ptr] 
00413538  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0E0h],eax 
0041353E  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-0E0h] 
00413544  push        ecx  
00413545  call        operator delete[] (4111E5h) 
0041354A  add         esp,4
```

Comment: i have read that , destructor will be called for first element in array, but whole memory will be freed, same i can see while debugging

Comment: No, only first element is freed, others not.

Comment: @Andrej: No, that's not sure. It might happen that way, but then it might not. For PODs, it's even likely that it might not. But you never know.

Comment: What will happen when `IP_ADAPTER_INFO` ceases to be POD type? Are you going to edit all the code? You have tagged your question with C++ tag, so you should consider using `std::vector`.

Comment: I highly recommend ignoring this question and instead reading [delete vs delete[]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255598/delete-vs-delete) instead, whose answers are much more to the point.

Comment: Delete is doing two things: invoking a destructor and freeing the allocated memory. In Visual C++ IIRC, either form of delete will correctly free the allocated memory - I would not expect the scalar form of delete to cause a memory leak or heap corruption when used on an array new. However, the incorrect delete will induce errors because of incorrect destructor invocation (only called on the first element when it should be called on each element of the array). This could lead to memory leaks or heap corruption, depending on what the destructor does (or fails to do because it wasn't called).

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Whether this leads to a memory leak, wipes your hard disk, gets you pregnant, makes nasty Nasal Demons chasing you around your apartment, or lets everything work fine with no apparent problems, is undefined. It might be this way with one compiler, and change with another, change with a new compiler version, with each new compilation, with the moon phases, your mood, or depending on the number of neutrinos that passed through the processor on the last sunny afternoon. Or it might not.

All that, and an infinite number of other possibilities are put into one term: *Undefined behavior*:

Just stay away from it.

Comment: I would say that "Undefined behavior" is "bad" and should be avoided, as you say. But this also means that in some cases it Will actually leak memory and You should Always code so that you solve worst-case scenarios. Thats my opinion anyways.

Comment: @Filip: assuming your own program invokes undefined behaviour? is that some evolved form of defensive programming?

Comment: +1 for being a correct. Talking about how `delete` and `delete[]` behaves in some specific implementation just gives the wrong idea. It's undefined behavior: don't do it.

Answer (score 14):

Just an illustration of some "undefined" behaviors on certain OSes and compilers. Hope it could be helpful for people to debug their code.

Test 1

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int *p = new int[5];
  cout << "pass" << endl;
  delete p;
  return 0;
}
```

Test 2

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int *p = new int;
  cout << "pass" << endl;
  delete[] p;
  return 0;
}
```

Test 3

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct C {
  C() { cout << "construct" << endl; }
  ~C() { cout << "destroy" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
  C *p = new C[5];
  cout << "pass" << endl;
  delete p;
  return 0;
}
```

Test 4

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct C {
  C() { cout << "construct" << endl; }
  ~C() { cout << "destroy" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
  C *p = new C;
  cout << "pass" << endl;
  delete[] p;
  return 0;
}
```

- Windows 7 x86, msvc 2010. Compile with default options, i.e. exception handler is enabled.

Test 1

```
pass
```

Test 2

```
pass
```

Test 3

```
construct
construct
construct
construct
construct
pass
destroy
# Then, pop up crash msg
```

Test 4

```
construct
pass
destroy
destroy
destroy
destroy
destroy
destroy
destroy
... # It never stop until CTRL+C
```

- Mac OS X 10.8.5, llvm-gcc 4.2 or gcc-4.8 generate the same output

Test 1

```
pass
```

Test 2

```
pass
```

Test 3

```
construct
construct
construct
construct
construct
pass
destroy
a.out(71111) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f99c94000e8: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
zsh: abort      ./a.out
```

Test 4

```
construct
pass
a.out(71035) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f83c14000d8: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
zsh: abort      ./a.out
```

- Ubuntu 12.04, AMD64, gcc 4.7

Test 1

```
pass
```

Test 2

```
pass
```

Test 3

```
construct
construct
construct
construct
construct
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001f10018 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7eb96)[0x7fe81d878b96]
./a.out[0x400a5b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7fe81d81b76d]
./a.out[0x4008d9]
======= Memory map: ========
....
zsh: abort (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

Test 4

```
construct
destroy
destroy
destroy
destroy
destroy
destroy
destroy
destroy
...
destroy
destroy
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000016f6008 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7eb96)[0x7fa9001fab96]
./a.out[0x400a18]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7fa90019d76d]
./a.out[0x4008d9]
======= Memory map: ========
...
zsh: abort (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

Comment: Your test still does not demonstrate whether there would be memory leaks.

Answer (score 7):

It will usually not leak because in case of POD destructors are trivial and there's no need for invoking them so `delete` just deallocates memory occupied by the array. Memory deallocation requires just a pointer value so it will be returned to the heap. The array accopies a contiguous block of memory and so the deallocation can be sucessful just as if it was a deallocation of a single element.

But don't rely on this since it is undefined behaviour. Maybe it works allright, maybe something horrible happens, works on this compiler, doesn't work on another and many people thank you for planting an error.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787417/why-would-you-write-something-like-this-intentionally-not-using-delete-on-an/793385#793385) for details.

Comment: Because `new T[]` may add an `sizeof` offset regardless of the POD-ness of T, in which case `delete[]` will compensate for this. `delete` would miss the header allocation block by a few bytes, interpreting an (possibly uninitialized) element count as a header, and cause unpredicatable heap corruption. Which of course shows up only when the boss looks.

Comment: Sure, that's why the word *usually* is there. And heap corruption is not a leak.

Comment: `struct A { void operator delete[](void *p, size_t t) { } };` even though `struct A` is a `POD`, `new A[10]` will allocate and store that size, and `delete[]` will have to retrieve it and pass it to operator delete

Answer (score 6):

**delete** :
    calls the appropriate **destructor only for the element** pointed to (if needed),
    then frees the memory chunk

**delete[]** :
    calls the appropriate **destructors for each element** in its array (if needed),
    then frees the memory chunk

Comment: All of this is true **only** if `delete` and `delete[]` are used correctly. This question is specifically about the case where `delete` is used where `delete[]` should have been used.

Answer (score 5):

Using delete operator on allocations with new T[n] is *undefined* and will vary from compiler to compiler. AFAIK, MSVC compiler for example will produce different code than GCC.

If A points to an array that was allocated via new T[n], then you must delete it via delete[] A. The difference between delete and delete[] is straightforward - the former destroys a scalar object and the latter destroys an array.

Comment: Nobody (not even Bjarne, let alone some Bjorn) specified that only one object would be freed. It's _undefined_. (And, as I said elsewhere, I have worked with at least one compiler which freed them all.)

Comment: I guess you mean Bjarne, not Bjorn?

Comment: sbi, the behavior for particular compiler *may* be undefined. But, as I said, this compiler is not following the C++ standard. Check http://www.research.att.com/~bs/. There is few mentions for this specific question.

Comment: _this compiler_ - I don't see a reference to a specific compiler (anymore) ? "Undefined Behavior" is an ISO Standard term, and does not refer to any specific implementation.

Comment: I'll repeat, this particular **behavior** is defined by a standard.

Comment: The C++ standard explicitly states (at least in it draft version from 13.9.2001 I have at hand) that such behavior is undefined:

In the first alternative (delete object), the value of the operand of delete shall be a pointer to a non-array object or a pointer to a sub-object (1.8) representing a base class of such an object (clause 10). If not, the behavior is undefined. In the second alternative (delete array), the value of the operand of delete shall be the pointer value which resulted from a previous array new-expression.72) If not, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @Andrejs: Chapter and verse, please.

Comment: The C++ Programming Language 6.2.6.2, 19.4.5

Comment: Neither of those exist in my copy (C++98). Anyway, the standard only specifies what you said before the updates: One destroys a scalar object, the other destroys an array. It does *not* say what you have in your first update, that if the scalar delete is invoked on an array, the first object is destroyed. That is **not** guaranteed by the standard. It is just undefined.

Comment: I would have upvoted but after reading "Update", i better not :(

Comment: Thanks jalf, sbi, Komat. You where right, I'd admitted my mistake and updated the post.

Comment: Please update your post so that all these conflicting updates are gone / or the correct information is on top

Answer (score -3):

For array of **POD** it will **not leak** (with the most compilers). For example, **MSVC** generates **identical** code for **delete** and **delete[]** for array of **POD**.

Personally, I think C/C++ could be without operator delete[]. Compiler knows object size and allocated memory size is known at runtime, thus it is very simple to know is a pointer array or not and dispose memory in a right way.

EDIT:

OK, guys. Can you test at your compiler and say whether it leak?

Try to think as a compiler developer. We have **new**, **new[]**, **delete**, **delete[]**. Each **new** has its own **delete**. Seems perfect and complete. Let's see what is going on when you call **delete[]**?

```
1. call vector destructor for an object
2. actual free memory
```

What is destructor for **POD**? Nothing!
So, calling **delete** for array of **POD** will not leak! Even if it breaks the standard. Even if it is not recommended.

EDIT2:

This is disassembly code generated by VS2008:

```
operator delete[]:
78583BC3  mov         edi,edi 
78583BC5  push        ebp  
78583BC6  mov         ebp,esp 
78583BC8  pop         ebp  
78583BC9  jmp         operator delete (78583BA3h)
```

Comment: `delete[]` is definitely not some form of optimization. It's all about correctness.

Comment: Yes, but is is superfluous. People want to know whether it will leak and I answered. Why downvote?

Comment: @Sergius: I can't speak for the others, but I down-voted it because you said "For array of POD it will not leak" - even though you somewhat played this down later. What this does is _undefined_. Period. (There are reasonable assumptions from which one can deduce possible scenarios, but they definitely won't fit all compilers or even compiler versions, so making such statement just seems wrong to me.)

Comment: Well, I said "(with the most compilers)". But thanks anyway! I will be more careful in my statement.