# Can you mix free and constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, free, malloc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any danger in calling free() or delete instead of delete[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612031/is-there-any-danger-in-calling-free-or-delete-instead-of-delete)

I was reading this question:
[In what cases do I use malloc vs new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new/)

Someone raised that one reason to use malloc was if you were going to use free.

I was wondering: Is it valid to mix a free call and a constructor initialization in C++?

i.e.

Can I say:

```
my_type *ptr = new my_type;
free(my_type);
```

Is that somehow invalid or worse than:

```
my_type *ptr = new my_type;
delete my_type;
```

other than the fact that it's not c++ish?

Likewise, could you do the opposite?  Can you say

```
my_type *ptr = (my_type *)malloc(sizeof(my_type));
delete my_type;
```

Please merge if this is a duplicate, I searched but didn't see a question along this lines exactly about malloc/delete/new/free asked.

Comment: Question is a dupe ( of a dupe ).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612031/is-there-any-danger-in-calling-free-or-delete-instead-of-delete

Comment: If you want to use malloc/free with C++ objects, you can use malloc and placement new operator to call a constructor and than call delete on it, and call free to release the memory. Or create a custom allocator when applicable.

Comment: @Vlad: Even after using placement new, you still can't call delete.  But you can manually call the object's destructor before sending the memory to free.

Comment: @Dennis, yeah you are probably right. Manual call to destructor and fee() is the way to go. Its been a long time since I used it :->

Comment: Just a minor note, my question is an exact dupe of the listed question.  The listed question doesn't cover malloc.  However, it does cover delete, delete[], and new, so it is mostly the same...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No it is invalid. There is no guarantee that `new` will use `malloc` or `delete` will use `free`.

Moreover, using `free` instead of `delete` will skip `my_type`'s destructor. If `my_type` itself is holding some resources, those will be leaked. Similarly, `malloc` will skip the constructor so the variable may be in an invalid state.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it valid to mix a free call and a constructor initialization in C++?

No it is not.

malloc,calloc,realloc -> free

new -> delete

new[] -> delete[]

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not valid. `malloc` (and other C allocation functions) must be matched with `free`, `new` must be matched with `delete`, and `new []` must be matched with `delete []`. While your compiler may not necessarily do anything differently if there is no destructor code, this is not something you should rely on.

The main difference is that new/delete call the constructor and destructor of an object; malloc and free just treat it as raw, untyped memory.

Answer (score 2):

1. `free()` does not call the destructor. It just deallocates the memory, no questions asked.
2. `new`/`delete` is not guaranteed to use `malloc()` as its memory allocator; `free` might not even know about the memory you're throwing at it

Comment: _@tdammers_, I think the phrasing of your 2nd point is a bit misleading: Why should `free` ever *use* `malloc` at all?

Comment: uh, I wasn't paying attention. Fixed it.