# What does delete[something] do in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I know this is not allowed by C++ standard and it does not compile on gcc, but I want to know why it works in Visual Studio.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "A()" << std::endl;
    }
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    A* arr = new A[n];
    delete[n] arr;
}
```

It behaves the same with `delete[] arr;`, `delete[n+5] arr;`, `delete[n/2] arr;`, `delete[-54] arr;` and even `delete[A{}] arr;`.

Comment: As you said, that is not allowed in standard C++, the brackets must be empty. `placement-new` allows additional parameters to be passed to `new`, but `delete` does not. If VS allows non-empty brackets on `delete[]` then that must be a Microsoft-specific extension, but I do not see it documented on MSDN, either [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/new-and-delete-operators?view=vs-2019), [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/delete-operator-cpp?view=vs-2019), or [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/microsoft-extensions-to-c-and-cpp?view=vs-2019).

Comment: I don't see it too, that's why I created this question.

Comment: With Visual Studio 2019 (version 16.4.4) I get a warning `warning C4208: nonstandard extension used: delete [exp] - exp evaluated but ignored`

Comment: It would be interesting to know the reasoning for introducing this in the first place. MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4208?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019 and what it does:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747976/c-array-delete-operator-syntax/1747994#1747994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned you should use `delete[] arr`. Otherwise you may get [Compiler Warning C4208](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4208?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019).

> With Microsoft extensions
>   [`/Ze`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/za-ze-disable-language-extensions?view=vs-2019),
>   you can delete an array using a value within brackets with the delete
>   operator. The value is ignored. Such values are invalid under ANSI
>   compatibility
>   [`/Za`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/za-ze-disable-language-extensions?view=vs-2019).

If you try to use `/Za`, you'll get [Compiler Error C2203](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2203?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019).

For more details I suggest you could refer to the link:
[C++ array delete operator syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747976/c-array-delete-operator-syntax)

Comment: `/Za` is only intended for C mode, as per Microsoft's own docs. It does not even make sense that it changes behavior for some C++ extension. One wonders...