# C++ delete static_cast<void*> (pointer) behavior

Tags: c++, casting, delete-operator

suppose the code does the following:

```
T *pointer = new T();
delete static_cast<void*>(pointer);
```

what is result?  Undefined, memory leak, memory is deleted?

Comment: Practically speaking, the memory will be freed without any destructor being called. Of course, this isn't standard behavior.

Comment: The other possible result would be a failed compile, ideally that should be what happens but not sure if fails to compile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behavior is undefined.  Concerning the delete expression, the C++ standard says:

> In the first alternative (*delete object*), if the static type of the operand is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the operand’s dynamic type and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined.  In the second alternative (*delete array*) if the dynamic type of the object to be deleted differs from its static type, the behavior is undefined.  (§5.3.5/3)

Then the footnote to this paragraph clearly states:

> This implies that an object cannot be deleted using a pointer of type `void*` because there are no objects of type `void` (note 73).

Comment: Yep, `+1` from me. As for what _UB_ means: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553382/pod-freeing-memory-is-delete-equal-to-delete/1553407#1553407 `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Deleting via  a void pointer is undefined, as is doing anything else via a void pointer except explicitly converting it to another kind of pointer.

Comment: Is it defined for any kind of pointer besides the type that was originally cast to `void*` in the first place?

Comment: I believe the conversion is defined. Using the pointer may not be.