# Is it safe to delete static casted pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-cast, static-cast

Consider abstract class `AbstractMap` and it's child class`MyMap`. Is it safe to perform the following delete operation? Or, should I delete the ptr only after re-casting to MyMap? And why? I guess it is unsafe, because in this case destructor of `MyMap` is not called.

```cpp
AbstractMap* ptr;
ptr = static_cast<AbstractMap*>(new MyMap());
delete ptr;
```

The [past question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709283/c-delete-static-castvoid-pointer-behavior) talked about casting to `void*` case, but I'm not sure for my case.

Comment: It will depend on whether `AbstractMap` is ready for polymorphism. (i.e. whether its destructor is marked as virtual)

Comment: It is allowed **only if** `AbstractMap` has a virtual destructor. If it doesn't, the behavior of the program is undefined.

Comment: The static_cast is not needed in the described case.

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks! Suppoes `AbstractMap` has a virtual destructor, how can it call the child class's destructor? I mean, say we have other many child classes of `AbstractMap`, how can it know that the "original" one is `MyMap`?

Comment: It doesn't have to do anything. `delete ptr;` will do the right thing: it will call the derived destructor, The derived destructor will do whatever it needs to do, then call the base destructor.

Comment: That's the magic of `virtual`. The correct version of the function is called in all cases. Behind the scenes this is typically implemented with [a "vtable"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Consider abstract class AbstractMap and it's child classMyMap.
> Is it safe to perform the following delete operation?
>
> ```
> ptr = static_cast<AbstractMap*>(new MyMap());
> delete ptr;
> ```

Deleting through a pointer to base sub object can be safe only if the destructor of the base (`AbstractMap` in this case) is virtual. If that precondition isn't satisfied, then the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> Suppoes AbstractMap has a virtual destructor, how can it call the child class's destructor?

Note that if you created the instance using allocating new expression, then you aren't supposed to call the destructor directly. `delete` will do that for you.

But in the special cases where you may need to call the destructor directly, you do it by calling the destructor of `AbstractMap` using dynamic dispatch (which is the default form of dispatch for virtual functions).

> how can it know that the "original" one is MyMap?

You don't need to know the dynamic type. That's what makes virtual functions so great.

---

P.S. Avoid owning bare pointers. There's hardly ever a need to write `new` and `delete`.

Answer (score 2):

Provided that `AbstractMap`'s (or it's base if any) destructor is marked as `virtual`, `delete ptr` would be well-defined.

Compiler will invoke the most derived destructor virtually (as with any virtual function), which will, in turn, call destructor(s) of base(s) non-virtually.

A destructor will have all necessary code to call destructors of all member objects,  and in the end of this process the memory will be reclaimed back to heap manager (based on size of allocated block).