# What are the dynamics of the C++ delete statement?

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator

This is merely for curiosity sake because I have not used `new` and `delete` in c++ except for the most basic uses.

I know that `delete` releases memory. The thing I'm wondering is how does it handle more complex cases?

For instance, if I have a user-defined class like this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass()
    {
        delete [] intArray;
    }
    //public members here
private:
    int* intArray;
};
```

Assuming the class allocates memory somehow for `intArray`, and then release it in the destructor, What if I used the class like this: `MyClass* myClass = new MyClass();` and released it later with `delete myclass;`

How does `delete` handle the releasing of all the memory? Does the class destructor get called first to release all of the memory allocated by the class (ie `int* intArray`) and then release the memory allocated to hold the class?

What if I had a class like this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass()
    {
        delete anotherMyClass;
    }
    //public members here
private:
    MyClass* anotherMyClass;
};
```

Assuming `anotherMyClass` is not allocated with the constructor, which would use up memory very quickly, what if there was a chain of MyClasses attached to each other like a linked-list? Would the delete statement in the destructor work in this case? Would each `anotherMyClass` be recursively released when the destructor gets called?

Are there any specific weird tricks or caveats with the `new` and `delete` statements that you know about?

Comment: Don't forget to have your own copy constructor and assignment operator. Handle the class' pointer members' dynamically allocated memory in them.

Comment: Yep, you've pretty much nailed it.  You've answered all your own questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given a pointer (`p`) to a dynamically allocated object, `delete` does two things:

1. It calls the destructor of the dynamically allocated object.  Note that when `~MyClass()` completes, the destructors for any member variables of class type are called.
2. It frees the memory occupied by the dynamically allocated object.

It doesn't search the member variables of the object for other pointers to free; it doesn't free any other memory and doesn't do anything else.

If you need to free the memory pointed to by `intArray`, you need to `delete` it in the destructor of `MyClass`.

However, in almost all C++ code, you don't need to worry about this.  You should be using smart pointers like `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, `auto_ptr`, and `scoped_ptr` to automatically manage dynamically allocated objects.  Manual resource management is difficult at best and should be avoided wherever possible.

This is part of a broader idiom, Scope-Bound Resource Management (SBRM, also called Resource Acquisition is Initialization, or RAII).  This is by far the most important design pattern to understand and to use everywhere in your C++ code.

If in your class you had declared this instead:

```
boost::scoped_ptr<int> intArray;
```

then when the `scoped_ptr<int>` object is destroyed, it will free the pointer that it holds.  You then do not have to do any work to manually destroy the object.

In well-written, modern C++ code, you should rarely need to manually use `delete`.  Smart pointers and other SBRM containers should be used to manage any type of resource that needs cleanup, including dynamically allocated objects.

---

In your second example, given a linked list that looks like:

```
x -> y -> z -> 0
```

you would have an order of operations that looks like this:

```
delete x;
  x.~MyClass();
    delete y;
      y.~MyClass();
        delete z;
          z.~MyClass();
            delete 0;
          [free memory occupied by z]
      [free memory occupied by y]
  [free memory occupied by x]
```

The objects in the linked list would be destroyed in reverse order.

Comment: Although, the calling of the destructor is guaranteed with exception of ... exceptions (and I guess when the power goes out). The destructor of all of your member variables are also called. You can take advantage of this "Cascade" with RAII techniques.

Comment: In other words, `delete` does not "release all of the memory allocated by the class", but the object being destroyed itself might do so and probably should.

Comment: Fixed some wording in my question. Wasn't entirely clear in the question about the first user-class example. I was wondering if the destructor got called first then memory was released, but you guys answered that question.

Comment: Also, if your class has members that are smart pointers (or otherwise have destructors), the destructor calls for those are included as an implicit final step of your classes destructor. If you manage to free the memory without calling the classes destructor, the members destructors won't be called either.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> delete intArray;
> ```

I assume `intArray` points to the first element of an `int` array? In that case, `delete intArray` yields undefined behavior. If you allocate via `new[]`, you **must** release via `delete[]`.

```
delete[] intArray;
```

Yes I know, `delete intArray`  might *[appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553382/)* to work just fine on certain systems with certain compiler versions under certain compiler options -- or it might not. That's [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/) for ya.

Also, you should follow the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/). Defining your own destructor but relying on the implicitly-defined copy constructor and copy assignment operator is a recipe for disaster.