# Question on abstract base classes in c++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Suppose class stringGetter contains exactly one pure virtual function: the overloaded paren-
theses operator, string operator()(int x). Also suppose that class getPageString is a
public stringGetter that implements operator().

Which of the following C++ statements will certainly result in a compiler error?

```
(a) stringGetter * a = new stringGetter;
(b) stringGetter * a = new getPageString;
(c) stringGetter * a;
getPageString * b = new getPageString;
a=b
(d) Exactly two of these will result in a compiler error.
(e) It is possible that none of these will result in a compiler error.
```

I'm a little fuzzy on abstract base classes, and I cant find good example cases online that do assignments like the ones below. I like asking questions on here about this kind of stuff, as I often learn more about things I wasnt even intending on learning. I cant even begin to make a guess on which of these would cause a compiler error. Can anyone go through a-c and tell me why or why not it would cause a compiler error?

Comment: Could you make this sound a little less like you copied it straight from your homework / interview?  Just sayin'.

Comment: Probably is homework, considering this other question asked a few minutes ago... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071069/behavior-of-simple-code-with-pointers-in-c

Comment: I notice this is the second question tonight that sounds like a homework question. Both would be quickly solved by just trying it

Comment: @cHao it's not homework. Its from an old exam and I'm reviewing for my own exam I got coming up tomorrow.

Comment: You should probably put that at the top of the question then.  We work on the honor system here; if you say it's not homework, it's not. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`(a)` results compiler error because instances cannot be created for abstract classes.

Comment: You know its abstract from the pure virtual but what is throwing me off is that its overloading the () operator which is already a valid operator.  So even though it virtual isn't it already implement?  I don't know if this question makes any sense.

Comment: I understand, he is overloading the operator `()`. Which means, OP is providing his implementation.

Comment: "You know its abstract from the pure virtual but what is throwing me off is that its overloading the () operator which is already a valid operator." <- It is?

Comment: @Crazy Eddie - If I am overloading an operator, doesn't it mean that I am providing my implementation overriding the default for the user defined type ? I understand that, we cannot change the default method signature of the operator.

Comment: @Mahesh - no, it doesn't mean that.  There's not a default for most operators wrt user-defined types.  Only `operator=` has a default.  Proof: `struct X {}; int main() { X x; x(); }` <- try to compile that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have instances of an abstract class, which rules out (a). Option (c) is just a more difficult way of doing (b).

Answer (score 0):

(a) - actual instantiation of abstract class (`new stringGetter`) takes place only there.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bit of a trick question. (a) definitely results in a compiler error, as already stated, and you've already gotten an excellent answer as to why. However, in option (c), there is no semicolon after the "a=b" statement. That'll result in a compiler error, too, as it's a syntax error. Note the question didn't say "Which of these will cause a compiler error due to the class instantiation?"