# Is it possible to run-time check if an iterator has not gone past the end() iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++14

I'm writing a code that divides a vector in to equal parts using simple arithmetic on the iterators. My logic might not be very good (although I'm fairly certain this is correct) which might mean I create an invalid iterator past end():

```
//selectWords is a vector<string>
//No is an unsigned integer.

unsigned wordNo = selectWords.size()/No; 
unsigned remainder = selectWords.size()%No; 

for(auto i = 0; i < No; ++i){
    unsigned extra = remainder ? 1 : 0;

    auto b = selectedWords.begin()+(i*wordNo);
    auto e = selectedWords.begin() + ((i+1)*wordNo) + extra;

    if(e > selectedWords.end()) throw logic_error("Iterator e in GridList::createGrids goes past the end of selectWords.") //shouldn't happen unless I've made a mistake.

    ...
    //do stuff
    ...

    if(remainder > 0) --remainder;

}
```

The part I'm curious about is `e > selectedWords.end()`. If `e` is already past `end()`, then it is an invalid iterator and I'm not sure whether there is any guarantee that the comparison operator provides defined behaviour. Indeed looking at Ben Voigt's post in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37209725/are-iterators-past-the-one-past-the-end-iterator-undefined-behavior) and 24.2.7 of N3337 it is clear that using iterator arithmetic to create a past-the-end() iterator is meaningless or illegal. Yet the ability to check whether an iterator is past end() requires that operations on past-the-end() iterators provide defined behaviour.

If it is not valid to do this comparison, is there any other way? Or do I just have to make absolutely sure my logic before compiling is correct?

Comment: If your iterator is end, and you add one to it; the implementation can return end() - meaning that your test of iterator > end will always be false.

Comment: You can test `((i + 1) * wordNo) + extra > selectedWords.size()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Going past an end iterator (e.g. incrementing it) gives undefined behaviour.

If something can only exist as a result of undefined behaviour, it cannot exist as a result of executing any operation in code that has well-defined behaviour.   Logically, that means there need be no defined way of testing for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply correct your code to get the right end position:

```
size_t No = 3;
std::vector<int> selectWords = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
size_t wordNo = (selectWords.size() + No - 1)/No; 
size_t remainder = selectWords.size()%No; 

for(size_t i = 0; i < No; ++i){
    size_t start_index = i * wordNo;
    size_t end_index = std::min(selectWords.size(), start_index + wordNo);
    auto b = selectWords.begin() + start_index;
    auto e = selectWords.begin() + end_index;
    for (auto it = b; it != e; ++it)
        std::cout << *it;
 //....
}
```

[Test it](http://cpp.sh/85avl)