# How do you do bounds checking with std span?

Tags: c++, c++20, outofrangeexception, std-span

`std::vector` and pretty much all other containers have a very convenient way of bounds checking: `at()`. `std::span` doesn't have that apparently.

- Why?
- Is there a replacement? Other than [rolling out your own](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4sj435) `at()`?

Comment: Why would you want that in a release build? Bounds checking is an anti-pattern, and only makes sense in the context of input validation. Otherwise, it's complicating control flow under the hood, which prevents essential optimizations. You should be using the iterator interfaces, primarily. IMHO, `at()` and alike exception based interfaces were a misconception which serves primarily to conceal logic errors further up at a significant overhead.

Comment: @Ext3h `at()` is great for debugging

Comment: @Axyan for debugging you have debug iterators  (toggled by corresponding defines) in most implementations. But as I said, usually you would not want to see them in production code ever, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::span::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/at) will be added in C++26.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty clunky but something like this:

1. using position

```
template<class Container>
auto& at(Container&& c, std::size_t pos){
    if(pos >= c.size())
        throw std::out_of_range("out of bounds");
    return c[pos];
}
```

2. using iterators:

```
template<class Iterator, class Container>
auto& at(Container&& c, Iterator&& it){
    if(std::distance(c.begin(), it) >= c.size())
        throw std::out_of_range("out of bounds");
    return *it;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using rvalue-reference parameters? doing move semantics?

Comment: @Ayxan the `Container&&` should be a forward reference, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/what-are-the-main-purposes-of-using-stdforward-and-which-problems-it-solves/3582313#3582313), so you don't need to redefine it for each const/non const ecc ecc type, infact `const std::vector<int> v{1,2,3}; std::cout << at(v, v.end());` should works fine

Comment: @JHBonarius see previous commet

Comment: I would say that these signatures are dangerous. Forwarding references can bind to rvalues, and then you return a reference (`auto&`) to something that is going to perish in a moment.

Comment: @Evg so you are saying that might be better using const reference?

Comment: @Evg `std::vector::operator[]`  does the same. No?

Comment: @Evg i can actually do something like this `std::cout << std::vector<std::string>{"a","b","c"}[2];` or `std::vector<std::string>{"a","b","c"}.at(2)`, so I think that is not that big of a deal

Comment: I just expressed my concern. Returning a reference to rvalue can be useful but is error-prone. What if you return `&&` for rvalues? Like [`std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get): it returns `T&&` if given an rvalue tuple, or `delete` an overload that takes rvalues, like [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref).

Comment: And why is it `std::distance(c.begin(), it) >= c.size()` and not `it == c.end()`? `std::distance` can take linear time, whereas iterator dereferencing is constant time.

Comment: @Evg because if you pass `c.end()+10`, with the `==` you won't get the real bound checking

Comment: `c.end() + 10` is [always undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62711210), even for `std::vector`, and what happens after UB is irrelevant.

Comment: @Evg Ayxan said that will use this code for debug, and so why we should care about this UB case when we can easily avoid it? PS: `at()` will get a `size_t`, so probably the version with the iteration won't be used

Comment: @Evg also `span` contains contagious memory container, which will have a constant distance evaluation, since you can probably just use the `operator-` between the 2 iterators

Comment: @Ayxan, it does. But the free function [`std::get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) does something different. Shouldn't free `at()` do the similar thing? I'm just asking.

Comment: `operator-` looks like a good alternative. Then this (generic) code won't compile for iterators that don't support constant time `std::distance`, and this is good.

Comment: @Evg I agree with both your points about rval reference and `operator-`. However, since this is only meant for debugging, it shouldn't matter either way.

Comment: @Ayxan Btw, GCC with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` reports assertion violation for out-of-bounds `[]` access on `std::span`: `Assertion '__idx < size()' failed.`.

Comment: Your function returns auto& but operator[] may return by value. I think you need to use something like decltype(auto).

Answer (score 2):

The [paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0122r7.pdf) that introduced span to the standard library says:

> **Range-checking and bounds-safety**
>
> All accesses to the data encapsulated by a span are conceptually range-checked to ensure they remain
> within the bounds of the span. What actually happens as the result of a failure to meet span’s boundssafety constraints at runtime is undefined behavior.

That is, the operations have narrow contracts, giving freedom to the implementer.

If your standard library doesn't let you control the behavior to the appropriate granularity. [gsl-lite](https://github.com/gsl-lite/gsl-lite) offers drop-in replacement with configurable contract violation behavior. The [Microsoft GSL](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL) was previously configurable, but [now](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/releases/tag/v3.0.0) always terminates on contract violation, discussed [here](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/1561) (which might actually be what you want).

Comment: "If your standard library doesn't let you control the behavior to the appropriate granularity" What does that mean? I want to write portable code if possible. Is this a part of the standard interface or not?

Comment: @Ayxan portable as in you'll be using it with multiple implementations, or portable as in open source? At present an arbitrary implementation could well omit any checks, although that might change in future if Contracts ever happens.

Comment: Portable as in, if I use `std::vector::at`, I know it will be doing bounds checking whether I am using GCC, Clang, MSVC or anything.

Comment: @Ayxan you can check that by reading documentation, source code and/or testing. There's no guarantee in the standard - the behavior on bounds violation is specified to be undefined.

Comment: @ayxan an at that has defined behaviour on all inputs is known as a wide contract.  One that does not is known as a narrow contract.  This answer states that the interface being a narrow contract was on purpose.  Narrow contracts permit bounds checking, but do not mandate it.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I think that was always the case for `operator[]`, and alternatively we had a separate wider-contract function (`at`) and I was wondering why this was not added to `span`.

Comment: @ayxan I'm not aware that a wide-contract accessor was considered at any point. Wide contracts are generally depreciated for the Standard library; see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1743r0.pdf

Comment: @ecatmur I meant to say back in ye old days, we had `at` for our containers like vector  and basic_string

Comment: @ecatmur while the paper explains why such wide contract is bad for production code, I wanted to use it for debugging purposes. I appreciate the link though, thank you.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili `at` throws an exception when the index is out of boundary. Going out of boundary in a `span` is regarded as violation of contract, and the behaviour is not controlled in code—as you can configure for no action, exception throwing, or termination.