# why return value of function can be assigned to?

Tags: c, function, return-value, lvalue

Consider the following function:

```
 char *f()
 {   
 char *s=malloc(8);
 }
 main()
 {
  printf("%c",*f()='A');
 }
```

If I comment the line `char *s=malloc(8);` I get an error as if the assignment `*f()='A'` accessed invalid memory. Since I never return any variable why does above assignment work at all?

2nd question: `'A'` is assigned to temporary variable created on return of function . So why can't `++a` etc. be used as lvalue?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Please post the exact error message.

Comment: Isn't there any warnings when you compile this code ? For example, that there is no return in f ?

Comment: just because you observe something to be working it doesn't mean it it works at all. `int min(int a, int b) { return a; }` this function works on average 50% of the time.

Comment: "Why does [it] work at all?" Because your compiler's warnings aren't high enough and/or you're extremely unlucky.

Comment: I use codeblocks. I know it is bad code .No warnings.So u mean in absence of return statement function returns a random address.What about 2nd question?

Comment: @sunny: What is `++a`? There is no `a` in your code.

Comment: I meant any postincrement preincrement etc cannot be used as lvalue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming return values are passed in registers, the return value from malloc might still be there when returning from f(). By pure chance.

When assigning to `*f()` you are not assigning to a temporary but to the memory returned from malloc. Assigning to ++a is totally different.

Comment: Although I miss they key phrase here - undefined behavior.

Comment: The question was why it **seemed** to work. Not if was correct.

Comment: I think the question is when and why you can assign to lvalues.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `f()` is not returning anything, you need to add:

```
return s;
```

But, in all honesty, this is just going to be the start of your problems.  You also need to `free()` the return value of `f()`.

I do not know why you have tagged this question C++, this is clearly C, and so I have untagged as such.

Comment: The question is asking, "X code is wrong but appears to be working, why?" and you're answering, "X code is wrong - you need to use Y code."

Comment: @Chris Lutz, ah.. Apologies.  I went in to septic shock when I saw the code and it clouded my judgement.

Comment: I've been there. I start seeing red when I see `void main()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the pointer in `f()` with the `return` statement, or else an illegal pointer will be returned:

```
char *f()
{   
    char *s=malloc(8);
    return s;
}
```

Comment: "...or else an illegal pointer will be returned" Where in the world does this come from?

Comment: Probably from my bad use of a foreign language. But what exactly is wrong with that statement?

Comment: That's not what happens, either according to the standard (which says undefined behavior) or in this real world example (the pointer from `malloc` is left over in the return register, effectively causing it to be returned from `f` as well).

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not return anything. Since you declare the function with the return-type `char *`, not returning anything results in undefined behavior, as defined in paragraph 6.6.3.2 of the current C++ Standard:

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a `return` with no
>   value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning
>   function.

Undefined behavior means that [anything can happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553382/pod-freeing-memory-is-delete-equal-to-delete/1553407#1553407). To fix that problem, your function should look like this:

```
char *f()
{   
    return malloc(8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function, you return a pointer where you can assign stuff... `++a` prevents it by returning `const` reference or instance. you can have the same behaviour if you have `const char* f() { ... }`.

Of course you could also implement `++a` differently :)

Answer (score 0):

1/ The return of f() is an uninitialized pointer, but exists.
*f() return the value pointed by an unspecified (random) address.
Writing at this address is an invalid memory access, or maybe not if this address is by "chance" a writable piece of memory (stack or previously allocated heap).
In C, it is your responsibility to ensure that you properly access the memory.

2/ 'A' is not assigned here to a temporary.