# Is this correct: virtual method of Derived called before constructing Base object?

Tags: c++, constructor, g++, standards, virtual-functions

I know that within constructor of Base class - when calling virtual method - the Base method is called, not derived - see [Calling virtual functions inside constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors).

My question is related to this topic. I've just wondered what happens if I call virtual method in Derived class constructor - but before constructing Base part. I mean calling virtual method to evaluate Base class constructor argument, See code:

```
class Base {
public:
  Base(const char* name) : name(name) {
    cout << "Base():" << name << endl;
  }
  virtual const char* getName() { 
    cout << "Base::getName()" << endl;
    return "Base";
  }
protected:
  const char* name;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived() : Base(getName()) {
    cout << "Derived():" << name << endl;
  }
  virtual const char* getName() { 
    cout << "Derived::getName()" << endl;
    return "Derived";
  }
};

int main() {
  Derived d;
}
```

Compiler g++ (4.3.x-4.5x versions) output is:

```
Derived::getName()
Base():Derived
Derived():Derived
```

However I'd expect:

```
Base::getName()
Base():Base
Derived():Base
```

This does not look wrong - but consider this example, which produces `segmentation fault`:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived() : Base(getName()), name(new string("Derived")) {
    cout << "Derived():" << Base::name << endl;
  }
  virtual const char* getName() { 
    cout << "Derived::getName()" << endl;
    return name->c_str();
  }
private:
  string* name;
};
```

Please answer: Is this correct g++ behavior? What C++ standard says about that? Maybe it is undefined behavior?

[UPDATE1]
I take into consideration Robert and Oli answers - and I changed my first example. Then it getName() is called "virtual" - and it produces Segmentation Fault. Please answer my question to this part too.

```
const char* virtualGetName(Base* basePtr)
{
  return basePtr->getName();
}

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  Derived() : Base(virtualGetName(this)) {
    cout << "Derived():" << Base::name << endl;
  }
  virtual const char* getName() { 
    cout << "Derived::getName()" << endl;
    return "Derived";
  }
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All of your examples exhibit undefined behavior.  The C++ language standard states (C++11 §12.6.2/13):

> Member functions (including virtual member functions) can be called for an object under construction.  Similarly, an object under construction can be the operand of the `typeid` operator or of a `dynamic_cast`.
>
> However, if these operations are performed in a *ctor-initializer* (or in a function called directly or indirectly from a *ctor-initializer*) before all the *mem-initializers* for base classes have completed, the result of the operation is undefined.

You are calling the member function `getName()` from the initialization list (the *ctor-initializer*) of the `Derived` class constructor.  This member function call must take place before the initializer for `Base` completes (the *mem-initializer* for `Base`) because it is an argument to the initializer itself.

Therefore, the behavior is undefined.

As a rule, [Never Call Virtual Functions during Construction or Destruction](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html).

Comment: I added update to my question, I believed more less like you answered - but now I really do not know why `segmentation fault` in last example. It seems that not always methods are called virtually. And vpointer to Derived::vtable is set at the beginning of ctor body (after {).

Comment: I have updated my answer.  My first two attempts to explain the behavior were catastrophic failures.  I'm fairly confident this latest explanation is correct :-).

Comment: @PiotrNycz: "Why the segmentation fault?" The behavior is undefined. A segmentation fault is [but one possible outcome](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1553407/140719) of invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: @James Thanks. This is the answer I was looking for. Can you add which std you are citing - C++03 and/or C++11?

Answer (score 1):

> I've just wondered what happens if I call virtual method in Derived class constructor - but before constructing Base part.

It might look like you're doing this, but you're not.

In your first example, `Derived::getName()` does not depend on `this`, so the method call works.  In your second example, `Derived::getName()` does depend on `this`.  Since `this->name` is not yet set, it points to an undefined location and gives you a segfault.

`this->name` is not yet set, because the first thing the `Derived` constructor does is call the `Base` constructor.  If you specify the parameters to pass to the `Base` constructor, it processes them first.  Then it instantiates the member variables of the class by calling their constructors.  The initializer list can be used to pass parameters to those constructors, but it cannot change the order in which they get called.  This step is where `name` gets initialized.  Finally, the body of the `Derived` constructor is executed.

Comment: Can you answer if this is defined behavior by C++ standard. Or it is undefined and specific to g++...

Comment: In your first example, `Derived::getName()` does not depend on `this`... Doesn't matter. It's UB. Whether `this` is involved just determines what might be a _likely_ outcome.