# delete ptr vs delete [] ptr

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is delete[] equal to delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553382/is-delete-equal-to-delete)

```
int main()
{
    char *ptr = new char[10];

    delete ptr;  // or delete [] ptr;
}
```

`delete []` is for arrays, and `delete` is for a single object, right? So, it should be `delete [] ptr;` in the above code, but it seems `delete ptr;` is also ok. Weird?

Moreover,

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    char *ptr = new char[x];  //cannot make sure whether it is a char pointer or a pointer to an array, right?
    // delete ptr, or delete [] ptr;
}
```

Comment: How many exact dupes of this question arise daily on SO...

Comment: As to your second point, an array of size 1 is still an array.

Answer (score 0):

Right. Delete ptr by `operator delete` when you use `operator new[]` is undefined behaviour.

> In the first alternative (delete object), the value of the operand of
>   delete may be a **null pointer value, a pointer to a non-array object
>   created by a previous new-expression, or a pointer to a subobject
>   (1.8) representing a base class of such an object** (Clause 10). If not,
>   the behavior is **undefined.**

Comment: And it is most likely a memory leak of n - 1. The second is an example of a complete memory leak, except when the main function returns, every modern OS will reclaim the application's memory and therefore make it moot, but that is a very bad practice.