# Why does the destructor of an overridden variable delete the new class's data?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, destructor

Following the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153153/initializing-array-of-variable-size-inside-a-class), I ran into an issue with overriding variables. This is the code I wrote to find the root of the problem:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class foo
{
private:
    int *bar;
    int l;
public:
    foo(int bar);
    ~foo();
    void print_bar() {
        cout << "bar = {"; for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {cout << + bar[i] << ", ";} cout << "}" << endl;
    }
};


foo::foo(int l) {
    this->l = l;
    cout << "Creating with length " << l << endl;
    bar = new int[l];
    cout << "{"; for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {cout << + bar[i] << ", ";} cout << "}" << endl;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < l; ++i) {bar[i] = 0;}
    cout << "Created with bar = {"; for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {cout << + bar[i] << ", ";} cout << "}" << endl;
}
foo::~foo() {
    cout << "Deleted with bar = {"; for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {cout << + bar[i] << ", ";} cout << "}" << endl;
    delete[] bar;
}


int main() {
    foo a = foo(1);
    a = foo(2);
    a.print_bar();
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
Creating with length 1
{0, }
Created with bar = {0, }
Creating with length 2
{0, 0, }
Created with bar = {0, 0, }
Deleted with bar = {0, 0, }
bar = {1431655787, 5, }
Deleted with bar = {1431655787, 5, }
```

Instead of what I expected:

```
Creating with length 1
{0, }
Created with bar = {0, }
Creating with length 2
{0, 0, }
Created with bar = {0, 0, }
Deleted with bar = {0, }
bar = {0, 0, }
Deleted with bar = {0, 0, }
```

How can I avoid this, or is there a better way to have a class with a variable length array as a parameter?

*(Please keep in mind when answering that I'm very new to c++.)*

Comment: Your `foo` class has incorrect copy semantics, as it does not follow the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), and go to the **Managing resources** section at that link (does the code look familiar?). -- *is there a better way to have a class with a variable length array as a parameter?* -- Use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: Note :  int *bar; is totally unecessary. It will only complicate things so avoid it.

Comment: *Please keep in mind when answering that I'm very new to c++* -- But you decided to get into the weeds of having to write a user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator.  That is not what someone very new to C++ should be attempting to do, until you learn exactly how to handle dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: If you are new to C++, you should be using `std::vector`, and not be using the advanced memory management features of `new[]` and `delete[]` (or `new`, `delete`, `malloc`, or `free`).

Comment: The issue with the link that you mentioned in your post is that it does not emphasize enough to use `std::vector`.  Instead it seemed to have steered you down the wrong track into attempting to use `new[]` and `delete[]`, and all it did was open up another can of worms.  I suggest you use good C++ books to learn from before trying to learn C++ by poking around looking at questions to give you ideas.  Nothing wrong with doing this, *if* you have the experience to know what you're looking for.

Comment: Terminology: you cannot override variables; you override virtual functions.

Comment: Also, don't use `l` as a name. It's often too hard to tell `l` and `1` apart.

Answer (score 1):

in the line, `a=foo(2)`, the default assignment was called, but the service it provided is not right in your case(it just copy memory byte to byte). You need to supply a customised copy of assignment operator, in which you need to destruct `*this` first.

```
class foo{
...
public:
   foo& operator= (const foo& f)
   {
       this->~foo(); // call the destructor explicitly !
       bar = nullptr; l= 0; // for exception safety.
       new (this)(f); // call the copy constructor to construct
                      // a foo object on this which can be regarded as
                      // raw memory (it's still a valid foo object)
                      // but treating it as raw memory has no harm
                      // as all resources (here memory) has been released.

                     // btw, this is placement new, 
                     // #include <new> 
                     // before you can use it.
       return *this;
   }

   // better yet in your case, a move assignment will be more efficient
   foo& operator = (foo&& f)
   {
         std::swap(*this, f); // this lazy way will do for your purpose
                             // experiment and see what actually happened
                             // and figure out why it's like that
         return *this;
   }
```

My bad. You don't have a copy constructor defined yet. You can define one like this.

```
      foo(const foo& f):foo(f.l)
      {
          for(int i=0; i<l; ++i)
             bar[i] = f.bar[i];
      }
```

And in the `main` function

```
int main() {
    foo a = foo(1);
    foo b = foo(3);
    a = foo(2); // this will call the move assignment operator
    a = b; // this will call the copy assignment operator
    a = std::move(b); // this will call the move assignment operator
             // make sure you experiment with all likelyhood
            // and understand the logic behind.
           // don't trust me or anybody without actual trying
           // and playing
    a.print_bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [PaulMcKenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3133316/paulmckenzie) and [Eljay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4641116/eljay) in the comments, I switched to [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to use as the variable length array.
Here's the updated (and working as expected) code for anyone confused:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class foo
{
private:
    vector<int> bar;
    int l;
public:
    foo(int bar);
    ~foo();
    void print_bar() {
        cout << "bar = {"; for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {cout << + bar[i] << ", ";} cout << "}" << endl;
    }
};


foo::foo(int l) {
    this->l = l;
    cout << "Creating with length " << l << endl;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < l; ++i) {bar.push_back(0);}
    cout << "Created with bar = {"; for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {cout << + bar[i] << ", ";} cout << "}" << endl;
}
foo::~foo() {
    cout << "Deleted with bar = {"; for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {cout << + bar[i] << ", ";} cout << "}" << endl;
}


int main() {
    foo a = foo(1);
    a = foo(2);
    a.print_bar();
    return 0;
}
```

(`foo::~foo()` doesn't have to be defined, I just left it there for consistency)