# Array of shared pointers to different classes

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to create an array of shared pointers to different types.
For example, something like that:

```
vector<shared_ptr<**???**>> v;
v.push_back(shared_ptr<int>(new int));
v.push_back(shared_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass()));
```

or any other way to pass `shared_ptr` without knowing its type.

Comment: Did you try to get a pointer from that vector? How do you want to detect the type cast you will need? -- Make all items in the vector inherited from a base class like "IObject". In that case you know the type of the vector and C++ allows you to safely cast.

Comment: Yes, but you ask for an array of shared_ptr<>. A pair is something different and might be useful.

Comment: You do not want to do that. (Instead of asking _"How do I do X in C++?"_, explain what your underlying problem is, and it's likely someone will come up with a solution that prevents you from doing this.

Comment: Try to use `std::make_shared` as it is more efficient.

Answer (score 27):

More type safe might be:

```
/// header #include <boost/variant.hpp>
typedef boost::variant < boost::shared_ptr < T1 >, boost::shared_ptr < T2 >, ... > VariantT;

std::vector < VariantT > container;
container.push_back ( boost::shared_ptr < T1 > ( new T1 ) ); // or boost::make_shared
container.push_back ( boost::shared_ptr < T2 > ( new T2 ) ); // or boost::make_shared
```

More take a look at the [Boost.Variant library](http://www.boost.org/libs/variant/).

Comment: Note that this approach only works provided you can constrain the types the variant supports at compile-time.

Comment: @bpw: How would you do otherwise? You cannot cast (and this always boils down to casting at some level or other) to a type you do not know at compile-time. The only way I can think of to deal with types unknown at compile-time is runtime polymorphism, which requires related types.

Answer (score 22):

Assuming you want to store objects that do not inherit a common class, the simplest way that comes to mind is to use [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html).

You still have to be sure about what's the type of each object stored at each index (i.e. to be able to perform the correct `boost::any_cast`).

You should do that rather than storing pointers to `void`. This is the closest as it gets to the semantically correct way of storing "something you know the type but the compiler doesn't", implying a cast when retrieving the value.

While both (`any` and a `void` pointer) will work the same way (pointer aside), if you cast to the wrong type, `any` will throw an `bad_any_cast` exception (IIRC), while with the `void` pointer, you'll get undefined behavior. A simple try on coliru yielded [**a segfault**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bcce05f2371353db).

Comment: Thanks. So there is no way of doing what I want with only c++11 tools?

Comment: Well, you could try to implement a solution for that, but I think it will end up very much like `boost::any` anyway. Oh and `boost::any` is a header-only boost feature, so there's not even the argument of having to link to an extra lib.

Comment: Actually, what you'll get its undefined behavior. That shows as a segfault _if you're lucky_.

Comment: `boost::any` is not a class template, it is a class.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin Right!

Answer (score 5):

Just as any fundamental pointer type is convertible to `void*`, any `shared_ptr` will convert to `shared_ptr<void>`:

```
vector<shared_ptr<void>> v;
v.push_back(make_shared<int>());
v.push_back(make_shared<MyClass>());
```

You now have a `vector` of fully type-erased shared pointers. You can't do much of anything interesting with it, however: you'd have to somehow know what types are stored in what slots of the `vector` to convert them back:

```
auto intptr = static_pointer_cast<int>(v[0]);
auto myclass_ptr = static_pointer_cast<MyClass>(v[1]);
```

So although it is *possible* to do this, it's not terribly useful and probably an indication of a broken design.

Comment: No, this isn't what you are looking for. Genericity through `void*` is bad and will lead you to write code that ___buggy, hard to fix, and hard to maintain___. Many of C++' constructs were invented exactly to get rid of this old C habit. [sfrehse's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26844776/140719) is way better.

Comment: Well, I learned something here. Didn't know that trick was possible. Of course I now have to make sure I never, ever do something that daft in my own code. Satus - please listen to everyone letting you know this is a broken design. You're mixing idiomatic C with idiomatic C++ and the only result can be fragile code.

Comment: @Satus - By removing type information entirely (in the `void*` solution), you lose safety, expressiveness, and performance. Safety because there is no check that you pull out the right type. A `variant` or `any` class is a *discriminated* union, which is to say, it *remembers and checks* its type. Expressiveness is lost because it could be *ANYTHING*, and that's dangerous and not self-documenting. Efficiency is lost because the compiler can no longer optimize based on type information. A discriminated union isn't as good as an actual type, but it's better than `void*`. Don't use this solution!

Comment: @Satus: I say _"You don't want to do that because it leads to code that's buggy, hard to fix, and hard to maintain."_ and you ask why you don't want to do this? I'm not sure what to answer to that.

Comment: @Satus - That's actually just entirely not true. I teach, I see this in office hours, latent bugs that present non-deterministically because sometimes the garbage you get is just close enough to what you needed that it works. You *might* catch it on the first run if you ran the program with valgrind. I have yet to see any substance in your commitment to this lousy approach, only laziness.

Comment: I couldn't possibly agree more with @Mark's comment. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1553407/140719) for what _Undefined Behavior_ means.