# c++ delete a newed array by using delete[]

Tags: c++

I know in c++ delete a newed array by using delete[].
What I am wondering is, what if I just do delete without [].
I saw something like this in our company code. And it does no crash the system.
Is this also right?

```
u_char* binBuf2 = new u_char[bitCount + 1];
delete binBuf2;
```

thanks

Comment: It's undefined behavior, that's all.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553382/is-delete-equal-to-delete/1553407#1553407

Comment: it is not correct, but it will work anyways, on *some* platforms. Dont use

Comment: _" I saw something like this in our company code."_ That sounds highly questionable, and should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

No that is not the correct method of freeing up the memory.

Keep in mind that because something doesn't crash the system doesn't mean it's good practice

Comment: (or even correct, sensible, defined, reproducible, or any combination thereof)