# Why can't I delete other-than-first element from array by pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory

Consider following code:

```
int main()
{
  int *intArPtr = new int[100];
  int *intArPtr1 = intArPtr + 1;

  delete [] intArPtr; //ok
  //delete intArPtr; //valgrind warning, but no leaks!
  //delete intArPtr1; //invalid pointer error

  return 0;
}
```

I know that `delete [] intArPtr` is the only valid way to delete this array, but I'm just curious about following:

1. Why `delete intArPtr` doesn't yield any memory leaks? Is it
   undefined behavior and I'm just lucky not to have any?
2. Why `delete intArPtr1` gives an error on run-time? Why doesn't it delete all elements but first from the array?
3. How does C++'s runtime knows size of the allocated array (for delete [])? Is it stored somewhere?

Comment: 3. Yes, the size of the allocated array is stored typically in the area before the pointer.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553382/is-delete-equal-to-delete

Comment: 1. and 2. Yes, it's undefined behavior

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 1. Why `delete intArPtr` doesn't yield any memory leaks? Is it
>      undefined behavior and I'm just lucky no to have any?

Correct, it is undefined behavior to call `delete` on memory allocated with `new[]`. For one, it won't call the destructors on the array members.

For two, even if you are just asking about memory deallocation and not about object destruction, it's possible for `delete` and `delete[]` to be implemented identically, or for them to be different. They read like they're the same thing but they're not: `delete` and `delete[]` are two different operators with potentially different implementations. They could use different allocation strategies (see the answer to question #3 below).

> 2. Why `delete intArPtr1` gives an error on run-time? Why doesn't it delete all elements but first from the array?

You have to pass `delete` a pointer allocated with `new`. The exact pointer. Not a pointer within a `new`-allocated memory region, that doesn't work. It has to be the same pointer to the start of the region.

> 3. How does C++'s runtime knows size of the allocated array (for delete [])? Is it stored somewhere?

A common allocator strategy is to store the number of bytes allocated right before the allocated region. `delete` would then take the pointer you pass it, look 4 or 8 bytes to the left, and interpret that integer as the size of the region. If you pass it a pointer to somewhere else its lookback strategy will fail.

The C++ language doesn't specify how memory allocation is tracked, so this is an implementation detail. Different standard libraries, compilers, and operating systems will do this differently. What I described is just one possible mechanism.

Further reading:

- C++ FAQ: ["What if I forget the `[]` when `delete`ing an array allocated via `new T[n]`?"](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-array)
- C++ FAQ: ["After `p = new Fred[n]`, how does the compiler know there are `n` objects to be destructed during `delete[] p`?"](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#num-elems-in-new-array)

Comment: That clarify a lot for me. Thanks!

Comment: `delete` and `delete[]` cannot possibly be "implemented identically". For POD types, the effects of calling either may be indistinguishable, but for user-defined types that contain pointers to other allocations owned by the objects being deleted, there is a profound difference between calling `delete` and calling `delete[]`, even on systems where the effects of using them incorrectly on POD types is indistinguishable. The key issue is that `delete` will call the type's destructor only once, for the object at [0], while `delete[]` will call the destructor for each object in the array.

Comment: @phonetagger: It certainly is possible for `delete` and `delete[]` to be implemented identically, if, for example, `new T` was implemented to have the same effect as `new T[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why delete intArPtr doesn't yield any memory leaks? Is it undefined behavior and I'm just lucky no to have any?

Yes and no at the same time. Using `delete` instead of `delete[]` is not clean, but usually works. Basically the pointer and offset are both stored at allocation time. This allows a proper deallocation to occur when using `delete`, even by accident.

2. Why delete intArPtr1 gives an error on run-time? Why doesn't it delete all elements but first from the array?

`intArPtr1` does not correspond to the pointer of the allocated area. When trying to `delete` that, the runtime cannot find this address in the allocation table.

3. How does C++'s runtime knows size of the allocated array (for delete [])? Is it stored somewhere?

It is stored in the allocation table, with the pointer to the allocated area.

Answer (score -2):

Answers:

1. No memory leaks in your exampe. As a matter of fact, deleting array without [] will only cause memory leaks if the objects inside arrays have some memory allocated themselves and are supposed to free that memory in the destructor. In all other cases, improper delete will not cause a memory leak.
2. Because the size of memory allocated is stored just before the pointer. When you are accessing any other element of the array but the first, there is no proper memory size there.
3. See 2.

Comment: 1. It depends on implementation - undefined behavior.