# c++ array of iterators

Tags: c++, dynamic-allocation, listiterator

Why does this code executed in debug mode trigger a breakpoint?

```
#include <list>

void main() {

  std::list<int>::iterator* iterators = new std::list<int>::iterator[50];

  delete iterators;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by breakpoint

Comment: change to `delete []`

Comment: An exception (iterators.exe has triggered a breakpoint.)

Comment: `delete [] iterators;`

Comment: What is `void main()`? It's *ancient*.

Comment: *Why does this code executed in debug mode trigger a breakpoint?* -- Ok, I have to ask the question -- does your real code actually do things like this?

Comment: Forgive me the 'void main' it was just to write a code snippet, thanks for the answers. I have to store some linked list element pointers, do you have a better way to do it? I know that they might be invalidated by some operations but I need to know given an element where it is placed in the list.

Comment: @acco93 *I have to store some linked list element pointers, do you have a better way to do it* -- `std::vector<std::list<int>::iterator> iterators(50);`  Then there is no need for `delete []`,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in comments, if you instantiate an array using

```
... = new name[];
```

you must use

```
delete [] name;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use the operator new[] you must also use the operator delete[], otherwise it is an undefined behavior.

You can check this question for more information:
[Is delete[] equal to delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553382/is-delete-equal-to-delete)