# What happen if I use non-array version of unique_ptr to hold an array?

Tags: arrays, new-operator, unique-ptr

I have the following piece of code:

```cpp
 // Read the file into this char array.
  std::unique_ptr<char> chars(new char[size + 1]); // Not using unique_ptr<int[]> ??
  chars.get()[size] = '\0';
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size;) {
    i += fread(&chars.get()[i], 1, size - i, file);
    if (ferror(file)) {
      fclose(file);
      return MaybeLocal<String>();
    }
  }
  fclose(file);
```

As you can see it, it is using `std::unique_ptr<char>` to hold the result of `new[]`, but not using `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`. If I recall it correctly, the default deleter of a `std::unique_ptr` just calls `delete` or `delete[]`, depending on the template parameter is an array or not.  It means I can simplified the above code to

```cpp
char *chars = new char[size + 1];
delete chars;
```

The code above seems to violate the principle that in general you should use `delete[]` to dispose what you `new[]` out.

- It is legal to manage a dynamic array via non-array `std::unique_ptr`?
- It is legal not to pair the `new` and `delete` w.r.t to array-ness? Or does it matter in practice?

**Edit**: I have learnt that mispairing `new`, `delete` and `new[]`, `delete[]` is undefined behaviour. Before being tagged as a possible duplicate, I update my post to ask whether this `unique_ptr` is also an UB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is delete\[\] equal to delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553382/is-delete-equal-to-delete)

Comment: You should completely avoid new and delete. Use std::make_unique instead.

Comment: OK I learnt it. The code is just UB. Adding `[]` to fix it.